# Equal divs depending on width?

Tags: html, css

How can I display different number of divs? For example the first section has three divs, the second section has two.

But they need to be the same width -  so the divs always fill the section, regardless of how many divs are there.

DIV -- DIV -- DIV 
DIV --------- DIV

I think I need to use max width? Is that right?

```css
section {
  width: 960px;
  background: grey;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  height: 200px;
  background: black;
  width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<section>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</section>

<section>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</section>
```

Comment: did you try max-width ? not clear to me what your asking , div all the same width or all rows filled no matter how many div on the rows ?

Comment: @GCyrillus Sorry - yeah all rows filled

Comment: So roberto and mickael answered to you , flex will manage this perfectly  from a single section via flex if wrap is set and min-width to tune max numbers of div on each rows ;)

Comment: @GCyrillus Brilliant, yeah that's exactly what I need!

Comment: okay, i made an answer from my comment to let you see how this idea works.

Answer (score 2):

```css
section {
  width: 960px;
  background: grey;
display: flex;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  background: black;
flex: 1 1 auto;
margin: 0 1rem;
}
```

```html
<section>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</section>

<section>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `display: table` on the parent, and `display: table-cell` on the children.

```css
section {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 0 1em;
  width: 100%;
}
section > div {
  display: table-cell;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>

<section>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

flex will manage this perfectly from a single section via flex if wrap is set and min-width to tune max numbers of div on each rows

```css
section {
  width: 960px;
  background: grey;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:space-between;
  padding:3px;/* equals, to fit children margins value */
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin:3px ;
  height: 200px;/* can be be min-height or removed to let tallest div to set row's height */
  background: black;
  min-width: 32%;
  flex:1;
}
.ha div {
height : auto;
color:white;
padding:1em;
}
```

```html
<section>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</section>
<hr/>
<section>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</section>
<hr/>
<section class="ha">
<div> hi <i>(let's height be)</i></div>
<div> the<br/>world</div>
</section>
```